# Bitbucket plugin version

Tags: php, bitbucket, sylius

I've created a private plugin repository with repman.io and added few Sylius plugins to it from my Bitbucket repository. I've faced an issue where in plugins `composer.json` file the version for example is 1.0.3, but when I try to pull it with composer it pull it only with `dev-master` or `dev-development` release versions. I don't know if this is related to Bitbucket or repman.io. I've tried to look on the internet how to change release version, but sadly didn't find anything. Is there any way to change the release version from `dev-master` to `1.0.3`? Thank you for your answers.

**composer.json**:

```
{
    "name": "omni/sylius-banner-plugin",
    "type": "sylius-plugin",
    "version": "2.2.3",
    "description": "OMNI package Sylius plugin, dedicated to banner management.",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1",

        "sylius/sylius": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpspec/phpspec": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Omni\\Sylius\\BannerPlugin\\": "src/" }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true}
```

This is what repman.io gives me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Xl1.png

Comment: How do you know it's `dev-master`?

Comment: When I try to require it with composer it conflicts with other packages, because it requires 2.2.3, but it gets [dev-master, dev-development]

Comment: Try creating tags for each version.